Received POST request error, how to handle？
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the request target [/t?personId=1308338881684471809&name=0xe40xbd0x950xe50xa40xa70xe70x840xb1&type=face_0&time=1716555197143]. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:486) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:261) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_251]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_251]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_251]



Invalid character found in the request target
I think it's possible that the requested URL contains special characters
Code has been added to the startup class
    @Bean
    public ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory webServerFactory() {
        TomcatServletWebServerFactory fa = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
        fa.addConnectorCustomizers(connector -> {
//                        connector.setProperty("relaxedQueryChars", "[]{}");
            connector.setProperty("relaxedPathChars", "\"#<>[\\]^`{|}%,");
            connector.setProperty("relaxedQueryChars", "\"#<>[\\]^`{|}%,");

        });

        return fa;
    }

But the error remains
Discover the existence of special characters by grabbing the bag
enter image description here
The sending side of the code can not be modified, can only modify the receiving side of the code, now need how to solve
After testing, I found that the encoding sent was UTF-8，My server version is Tomcat9.0.38.At the moment I am dealing with special symbols, but the results do not seem to solve the problems encountered,I've also configured ‘spring.http.encoding.charset’ and ‘server.tomcat.url-encoding.charset’ Encoding. Charset I think it might be a good idea to allow all of Utf-8's encoding, and I'm currently trying to figure out how to do that.

It looks like the sender side has encoding issues when setting the name in the request. Do you know what the original name value was or which language/encoding was? I guess that if the sender sends garbage characters it is hard for you to do something.

(1) curl -X POST "http://localhost:8080/t?personId=1308338881684471809&name=何大焱&type=face_0&time=1716555197143"
will get same error
(2) encode "何大焱" to "%E4%BD%95%E5%A4%A7%E7%84%B1" ,
curl -X POST "http://localhost:8080/t?personId=1308338881684471809&name=%E4%BD%95%E5%A4%A7%E7%84%B1&type=face_0&time=1716555197143",
you can pass.
(3) This is Tomcat 8.5+ Apply HTTP RFC 7230 and RFC 3986 , you can add some extra chars in  relaxedPathChars  & relaxedQueryChars , but out of these extra chars, is still failed.

Encoding Issue "The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986" in Tomcat 9 (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56794459/encoding-issue-the-valid-characters-are-defined-in-rfc-7230-and-rfc-3986-in-to)

If you insist on The sending side of the code can not be modified, this problem should not be solved.

There doesn't seem to be a good solution at the moment, with JSON data being pushed, so the URL query parameters are not used, and I use NGINX to eliminate the following illegal query parameters
